# Special handling of Ctrl-J

Tags: terminal, terminal-emulator, virtual-consoles

When I press <kbd>Ctrl-V</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl-J</kbd> in a shell (under `urxvt`), it starts a new line (positions the cursor at the beginning of a new line), instead of printing `^J`.

In `vim` it prints `^@`.

The same situation is in the virtual console.

Apparently something preprocesses <kbd>Ctrl-J</kbd>. What is it, and how do I influence it?

```
$ stty -a
speed 38400 baud; rows 26; columns 101; line = 0;
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^?; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = <undef>;
eol2 = <undef>; swtch = <undef>; start = ^Q; stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; rprnt = ^R;
werase = ^W; lnext = ^V; discard = ^O; min = 1; time = 0;
-parenb -parodd -cmspar cs8 -hupcl -cstopb cread -clocal -crtscts
-ignbrk brkint ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr icrnl ixon -ixoff
-iuclc -ixany imaxbel iutf8
opost -olcuc -ocrnl onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0 ff0
isig icanon iexten echo echoe echok -echonl -noflsh -xcase -tostop -echoprt
echoctl echoke -flusho -extproc

$ echo $TERM
rxvt-unicode-256color

$ urxvt --help |&  head -1
rxvt-unicode (urxvt) v9.26 - released: 2021-05-14
```

**UPD** I was configuring `tmux` and such behavior made me think that `bind-key C-j send-keys C-j` doesn't work.

Comment: Does it happen or Bash or in other shells too?

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk In `bash-5.1.12`. Don't know about the other shells.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Arkadiusz Drabczyk said, `readline` is responsible for handling of `C-v`. Particularly `C-v C-j`. It just [handles](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/readline.git/tree/display.c?h=readline-8.1&id=cf3c762ecfff5b2f445647a0f1543693984a5540#n1100) them [differently](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/readline.git/tree/display.c?h=readline-8.1&id=cf3c762ecfff5b2f445647a0f1543693984a5540#n1110). Supposedly because `C-j` (`Enter`) can be represented in a meaningful way w/o the `^*` notation. And the letter in that notation is obtained by [or'ing `0x40`](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/readline.git/tree/chardefs.h?h=readline-8.1&id=cf3c762ecfff5b2f445647a0f1543693984a5540#n67) to the character code, if you're curious. Or you might say, `0x01` corresponds to `^A`, `0x02` to `^B`, and so on.

As for `vim` that (`^@`) is also how it [represents newlines](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/v8.2.4027/src/charset.c#L562-L563). And there are a couple of mentions in the documentation:

> You can also use `<NL>` to separate commands in the same way as with `'|'`.  To
> insert a `<NL>` use `CTRL-V CTRL-J`.  `"^@"` will be shown.

https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/v8.2.4027/runtime/doc/cmdline.txt#L652-L653

> *NL-used-for-Nul* 
> Technical detail:
> `<Nul>` characters in the file are stored as `<NL>` in memory.  In the display
> they are shown as `"^@"`.  The translation is done when reading and writing
> files.  To match a `<Nul>` with a search pattern you can just enter `CTRL-@` or
> `"CTRL-V 000"`.  This is probably just what you expect.  Internally the
> character is replaced with a `<NL>` in the search pattern.  What is unusual is
> that typing `CTRL-V CTRL-J` also inserts a `<NL>`, thus also searches for a `<Nul>`
> in the file.

https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/v8.2.4027/runtime/doc/pattern.txt#L1273-L1280

Probably it has something to do with storing null bytes as newlines in memory.

Answer (score 1):

C-v in Bash is processed by readline:

```
$ bind -p | grep '"\\C-v":'
"\C-v": quoted-insert
```

As explained in readline(3):

```
   quoted-insert (C-q, C-v)
          Add the next character that you type to the line verbatim.  This
          is how to insert characters like C-q, for example.
```

You can use C-v to insert other characters, for example C-v C-i will
insert tab. To know which letter produces the given character open
`man ascii`:

```
       Oct   Dec   Hex   Char                        Oct   Dec   Hex   Char
       ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
       000   0     00    NUL '\0' (null character)   100   64    40    @
       001   1     01    SOH (start of heading)      101   65    41    A
       002   2     02    STX (start of text)         102   66    42    B
       003   3     03    ETX (end of text)           103   67    43    C
       004   4     04    EOT (end of transmission)   104   68    44    D
       005   5     05    ENQ (enquiry)               105   69    45    E
       006   6     06    ACK (acknowledge)           106   70    46    F
       007   7     07    BEL '\a' (bell)             107   71    47    G
       010   8     08    BS  '\b' (backspace)        110   72    48    H
       011   9     09    HT  '\t' (horizontal tab)   111   73    49    I
       012   10    0A    LF  '\n' (new line)         112   74    4A    J
       013   11    0B    VT  '\v' (vertical tab)     113   75    4B    K
       014   12    0C    FF  '\f' (form feed)        114   76    4C    L
       015   13    0D    CR  '\r' (carriage ret)     115   77    4D    M
```

As you can see J is on the same line as new line and I is one the same
line as horizontal tab.

You can check yourself with other examples such as C-v C-g that will
produce bell:

```
$ printf ^G| hexdump -C
00000000  07                                                |.|
00000001
```

Comment: Good point about `readline` handling `C-v`. But the way it looks... Usually with `C-v C-<letter>` you get `^<letter>`. But in case of `C-j` I get a newline. Which makes me think that `readline` doesn't get a change to process `C-v C-j` or just `C-j`. Maybe `rxvt` or the kernel preprocesses it somehow. I expected it to print `^J`. Also, `man tab` doesn't work for me. Can you provide a link to the manual page?

Comment: @x-yuri: sorry, I meant `man ascii`, fixed